# ElasticSearch update query using NOT and AND to be ES 5.5 compatible

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I need to update this query to be ES 5.5 compatible (NOT and AND are deprecated).

```
:and => [
  {
    term: {
      type: 'group'
    }
  },
  {
    :not => {
      terms: {
        group_id: group_ids
      }
    }
  },
  {
    :not => {
      terms: {
        user_id: user_ids
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
:bool => [
  :filter => [
    {
      term: {
        type: 'group'
      }
    }
  ],
  :must_not => [
    {
      terms: {
        group_id: group_ids
      }
    },
    {
      terms: {
        user_id: user_ids
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Doesn't that say must not have an id that's in the array? I want the opposite, I don't want any items with IDs that are not in the given array.

Comment: The full query is huge but I will pair it down and show some more of it.